# Foreach each element, but they may repeat

Tags: c#, parsing, foreach

I have an array of tags that may appear in console as color tags. There's 37 of them.

So, I do this code:

tagsCT is a string[]

```
foreach (string tag in tagsCT)
{
    if (text.Contains(tag))
    {
    ArrayList x = new ArrayList();
    x.Add(tag);
    x.Add(tagsColorValues[k]);
    tagss.Add(text.IndexOf(tag));
    tags.Add(text.IndexOf(tag) - 1, x);
    }
k++;
}
```

What do I have:
    text = "2013-11-11 17:56:14 [INFO] $4/time: $5Changes the time on each world"
What I need to do is find all the color tags in the string. All the possible ones are
in an array string[]

```
tagsCT = { "$1","$2","$3","$4" }
```

I show it as an example, but the tags aren't always the same length.
But the problem strikes in these situations:

```
text = "2013-11-11 17:56:14 [INFO] $4/time: $5Changes the time on each $4world"
```

The last tag will not be detected. The question is how to prevent it.

Comment: I am unable to decipher a question here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: give an example of the problem, the data set

Comment: Why not try a generic dictionary: Dictionary<int, string> or vice versa - sounds like you just want to count occurrences - I'd consider scanning the string by index too if it helps (depends how performant the code needs to be)

Comment: Find all the matching color tags from an array in a string. I need to save their indexof in the string, and the tag itself to a dictionary<object,object>, where the key is the index of occurrence, and the value is an arraylist containing the tag itself and it's corresponding color value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, IList<int>>` instead:

```
var tagIndices = new Dictionary<string,  IList<int>>();
foreach (string tag in tagsCT)
{
    IList<int> indices;
    if (tagIndices.TryGetValue(tag, out indices))
        continue; // to prevent the same indices on duplicate tags, you could also use a HashSet<string> instead of the array
    else
    {
        indices = new List<int>();
        tagIndices.Add(tag, indices);
    }
    int index = text.IndexOf(tag);
    while (index >= 0)
    {
        indices.Add(index);
        index = text.IndexOf(tag, index + 1);
    }
}
```

Each tag is stored as key and the value is the list of indices (can be empty).

Here's a <kbd>[**demonstration**](http://ideone.com/GU0vmk)</kbd>

Comment: Yes but what if now two same tags are in that string text?

Comment: @niklon: So the array contains duplicate tags, why? However, it doesn't cause an exception but the indices would be added multipe times. If you don't want this you either have to use a `HashSet<string>` instead of your array (to prevent duplicates) or you have to add an `else` block to the `if` above which simply `continue`s the `foreach`.

Comment: I didn't mention that in the question, but I need the Key to be the IndexOf of each tag, because then I'm going to sort the whole thing, and begin the color parsing. The Value for each key has to be the tag itself as string and it's corresponding color tag.

Comment: No no, duplicates aren't in an array. They are in the string "text", and if a tag repeats in it the loop doesn't come back to it.

Comment: I will add exactly what am I trying to do to the question.

Comment: @niklon: i don't understand it, the loop above can handle multiple matches in the text. That's the whole point of the list and the [`IndexOf` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx) with the start index. I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: I added it to the question. Or I just don't simply understand the code you've posted.

Comment: @niklon: i have tested your sample text and your array and the last tag will be detected with index 27. All tags are added to the dictionary but only the last tag's list(the value in the dictonary) is not empty. It has a single index.

Comment: On line     index = text.IndexOf(tag, index + 1); in your code I get an "Index out of range" error.(startIndex)

Comment: Oh, that's because of another thing I forgot to mention. That the index must be - 1 for each, because of a starting character before each color tag.

Comment: @niklon: if you have problems to understand the code, i have added a demo-link where you can see it in action. At the bottom is the output. **Edit** I don't understand your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about, after you've processed the tag, remove it from the "text" string?
You could also use a `for(int i;;i)` structure using the IndexOf value.
(sorry, where the hell is he comment button then?)

Comment: It would destroy all my current parsing, I used to do it but I really didn't like the solution.

Comment: Its probably because you dont yet have a score of 50 that is required to comment.  Getting there though.

Comment: Yeah it is here on other comments but not on the main question,